# CSS not displaying properly in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome

I created an iFrames page tab on Facebook, which displays just fine in FF and IE, but has messed positioning of divs in Chrome. The link to the page is: http://allcdmania.com/silvernoise-facebook/recommended.html

What's strange is that the only problems I have are on this page. All the other pages display just fine in all browsers.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: i'd start by making sure all url's have proper url encoding - you have tons of validation  errors because of this... see http://validator.w3.org/

Comment: Well, all of my links are written in this way: 
<a href="http://itunes.apple.com/us/album/in-and-out/id427206462" target="_blank"><img src="images/button-itunes.png" width="56" height="23" alt="iTunes Button"/></a>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is strange as soon as you inspect the code it shows fine, what I would suggest is place the styles you have on body and html on the #container element.

Also you could try using display:block; on your html tag

```
  #container {
    background-image: url("../images/silvernoise-bg-recommended.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    width: 510px;
    height: 780px;
    font-family: lucida sans, candara, sans-serif;
    font-size: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    display:block;
}
```